# Strange compiler error: found Unit, where I try to return a Double

Tags: function, scala, recursion

My code:

```
def power(x: Double, n: Int): Double = {
  if (n % 2 == 0 && n > 0) power(power(x, n/2), 2)
  else if (n % 2 == 1 && n > 0) x * power(x, n - 1)
  else if (n == 0) 1
  else if (n < 0) 1 / power(x, -n)
}

println(power(2, 2))
```

Terminal:

```
$ scala ch2ex10.scala 
/scala/impatient/ch2ex10.scala:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Double
  else if (n < 0) 1 / power(x, -n)
```

Where is this `Unit` coming from?

Thanks!

Comment: I allowed myself to change the error message, which seemed to me too localized to what was incidentally related to the error, which can be quiet common and occur in completely different situations - not related to power functions at all. Of course it is easy to tell this after finding out the cause of the error. But for future visitors, it will probably help them to find the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes from the last "else if" in the block.

It doesn't look like all possibilities are exhausted. If there is no other possibility left (which happens to be the case here), just write

```
 else 1 / power(x, -n)
```

if another possibility would be open, you would need to write

```
 else if (n < 0) 1 / power(x, -n)
 else ...
```

and fill out the dots. Else the compiler assumes

```
 else {}
```

for you.